# How to edit the Salesforce Live agent button?

Tags: liveagent, digital-engagement

I am quite new with Salesforce digital engagement and I could not find how can I customize the chat button to fit my Website

Right now the button looks like the following:

[image]

How can I edit the CSS? Make it bigger, smaller change colors, the font

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to edit this button styling from this clickpath

`Setup> Embedded service deployments(ESW)>'view' your ESW by clicking the dropdown> Branding`

See more info on [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/web-chat/web_chat_branding) and [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.snapins_chat_branding.htm&type=5)

Incase you want to change the "Agent offline" button you can do that from experience site> Builder> Theme>Colors> Action color

Also, the color and label of the chat button can be changed directly on the embedded service code snippet if you’re deploying on a Visualforce Page or external website.

Here’s the section of the code snippet where you can changed the chat button color (its on the beginning of the code snippet):

```
<style type='text/css'>
.embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton {
background-color: #57C046;
font-family: "Salesforce Sans", sans-serif;
```

And here’s where you can change the label of the displayed message if there are online agents or none (its on the middle portion of the code snippet):

```
//embedded_svc.settings.defaultMinimizedText = ‘…’; //(Defaults to Chat with an Expert)
// embedded_svc.settings.disabledMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Agent Offline)
```

The 3 dots closed by quotation is where you can put your desired message that the customer will see. And don’t forget to remove the 2 forward slash at the beginning of each code line so that the changes will reflect.